# colMeans of a sparse matrix times a matrix stored as the last element of a list

Tags: r

I want to get the column means for the last list element, which is a sparse matrix multiplied times a regular matrix.  Whenever I use colMeans, however, I get an error.  For example:

```
# Use the igraph package to create a sparse matrix
library(igraph)
my.lattice <- get.adjacency(graph.lattice(length = 5, dim = 2))

# Create a conformable matrix of TRUE and FALSE values
start <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 50, replace = T), ncol = 2)

# Multiply the matrix times the vector, and save the results to a list
out <- list()
out[[1]] <- my.lattice %*% start
out[[2]] <- my.lattice %*% out[[1]]

# Try to get column means of the last element
colMeans(tail(out, 1)[[1]])  # Selecting first element because tail creates a list
# Error in colMeans(tail(out, 1)[[1]]) : 
#  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

# But tail(out, 1)[[1]] seems to have two dimensions
dim(tail(out, 1)[[1]])
# [1] 25  2
```

Any idea what's causing this error, or what I can do about it?

Comment: Whoops!  I meant to take a sample of size 50.  It's fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Try `Matrix:::colMeans(out[[2]])` to explicitely call the `colMeans` from `Matrix` - to work on the matrix of class `"dgeMatrix"`. So using your code `Matrix::colMeans(tail(out, 1)[[1]])`

Comment: @user20650, `Matrix::colMeans` did the trick, thanks!  I don't know why I didn't think to try that.

Comment: `colMeans(as.array(tail(out, 1)[[1]]))` works too.

Comment: @Rstudent, good point, but i wonder if `Matrix:::colMeans` is more efficient by retaining the sparse nature of the matrix or if it also internally coerces to a *normal* matrix??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like explicitly calling the colMeans function from the Matrix package works:

```
> Matrix::colMeans(tail(out, 1)[[1]])
# [1] 4.48 5.48
```

Thanks to user20650 for this suggestion.